# Convexification of an optimization problem with bilinear constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, bilinear-form, non-convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem:

\begin{align*}
\min\;&f(x)\\
\mathrm{s.t.}\;&\rho^\top \mathbf{1}=1\\
& \rho^\top g+w^\top G\leq y\\
&w^\top w+\rho^\top \rho-z^2\leq 0\\
&z\geq 0\\
&w =\rho \circ x
\end{align*}

where $g$ and $G$ are given constants. I have a few more constraints incorporating $x,z$ and $y$, which are convex. My issue is the last constraint which is bilinear. I wonder is there a way to convexify this problem? I have tried using McCormick relaxation but the resulting constraint is too loose.

Comment: The tightest convex relaxation you can attain is via the convex hull of a set. There are numerous ways to calculate it, and it might not be easy. My preferred method is via the bi-conjugate. Take the non-convex constraint and set it as your objective function. The other functions will serve as constraints. Calculate the convex conjugate of that function. Then the bi-conjugate. Now you have the convex-hull of the original constraint set, and you can use it as a constraint set on your original problem

Comment: What is $f$? Can you perhaps substitute $x$ out?

Comment: $f(x)$ is quadratic function, but I have some more constraints for $x$, so I cannot substitute it.

Comment: Throw it in a branch and bound global optimizer, and let it deal with the bilinear constraint.